# Order of User agents in robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

my robots.txt looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /test

User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /maps
```

Now Google ignores the user-agent * part and only obeys the specific Googlebot directives (/maps). Is this normal behaviour and shouldn't also obey the useragent * directives (/admin, /test)?

It seems strange to have to add every line for every useragent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, Google states this:

> Each section in the robots.txt file is separate and does not build
>   upon previous sections. For example:
>
> User-agent: * Disallow: /folder1/
>
> User-Agent: Googlebot Disallow: /folder2/
>
> In this example only the URLs matching /folder2/ would be disallowed
>   for Googlebot.